# ruby code stopping at run time, seemingly an infinite loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, infinite-loop

if i run the code, it will stop and not do anything and i am unable to type. seems to be an infinite loop.
the problem seems to be the end until loop, however if i take that out, my condition will not be met.
can anyone find a solution? i have tried all the loops that i can think of.

```
/. 2d array board ./

board = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10, 0) }

/. printing board ./

if board.count(5) != 5 && board.count(4) != 4 && board.count(3) != 3

  for i in 0..9
    for j in 0..9
      board[i][j] = 0
    end
  end

  aircraftcoord1 = (rand*10).floor
  aircraftcoord2 = (rand 6).floor
  aircraftalign = rand
  if aircraftalign < 0.5
    for i in 0..4
      board[aircraftcoord2+i][aircraftcoord1] = 5
    end
  else
    for i in 0..4
      board[aircraftcoord1][aircraftcoord2+i] = 5
    end
  end

  cruisercoord1 = (rand*10).floor
  cruisercoord2 = (rand 7).floor
  cruiseralign = rand
  if cruiseralign < 0.5
    for i in 0..3
      board[cruisercoord2+i][cruisercoord1] = 4
    end
  else
    for i in 0..3
      board[cruisercoord1][cruisercoord2+i] = 4
    end
  end

  destroyercoord1 = (rand*10).floor
  destroyercoord2 = (rand 8).floor
  destroyeralign = rand
  if destroyeralign < 0.5
    for i in 0..2
      board[destroyercoord2+i][destroyercoord1] = 3
    end
  else
    for i in 0..2
      board[destroyercoord1][destroyercoord2+i] = 3
    end
  end

end until board.count(5) == 5 && board.count(4) == 4 && board.count(3) == 3


print " "

for i in 0..9
  print i
end

puts

for i in 0..9
  print i
  for j in 0..9
    print board[i][j]
  end
  puts
end
```

Comment: Don't use `end until...`. Your condition is tested in the opening `if`. If you need it to loop, use `loop` and define your break condition. As a stylistic thing, don't use `for`, like `for i in 0..4`, instead use `5.times do |i|`. Also, we comment code using `#`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `board.count(5) == 5 ...` will never be true because `board` is a two-dimensional array. I can't tell what the condition should be, but it could look something like:

```
  board[5].count(5) == 5
```